# How to use jquery to fade in different select field attributes based on clicking on link/button above

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, forms, dynamic

```
  = simple_form_for @item, :controller => "items", :action => "new", do |f|
  = render 'shared/messages', :object => @item

    fieldset
    legend Create Item
    h5 What are you listing?
    a.dress dress
    a.bottoms bottoms
    a.tops tops
    span#dresses style="display:none;"
        # if dress is clicked, then the f.select values different values. 
        # example values would be "green, white"
    span#bottoms style="display:none;"
        # if bottom is clicked, then the f.select values different values. 
        # example values would be "pink, orange"
    span#tops style="display:none;"
        # if tops is clicked, then the f.select values different values. 
        # example values would be "aqua, blank"

    f.select :color, "select values based on clicked above"
```

My end goal is so when I click on "dress", that jquery will update the value properties, for the select :color, as each would be different.  Each a link clicked above would then popular a different set of select values for the :color select field.

Having a hard time finding an elegant way to handle this.

Thanks

Comment: What does the actual HTML markup look like when you generate this? is it <a href="#dress"> Dress </a>? I'm not a ruby aficionado.

Comment: In rails if I simple add a class, the html looks like: <a class="dress">dress</a>, the select area looks like: <select id="item_color" name="item[color]"><option value="Black">Black</option>

Comment: [Check out this jsFiddle I made for you](http://jsfiddle.net/SFP36/) -- Does this reasonably tackle your issue?